# Is there an efficient alternative to "Not In" in MS Access Query?

Tags: ms-access

It appears that doing a `Not In` query is expensive in MS Access, as these queries generally run very slowly. Is there an alternative method to conduct such a query as to avoid this overhead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))!!!

[image: Joins]

Using either the `Left Join` or `Right Join` should do what you want! (Include the `WHERE` Clause `IS NULL`

(So that's either the middle left or middle right diagrams.)

So it will be something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table a
LEFT JOIN Table b
ON a.Value = b.Value
WHERE b.AnotherOrSameValue IS NULL
```

---

**Please Note**

As HansUp has informed me, The `Full Outer Join` is not available for MS Access SQL (that's the lower right diagram)

Comment: Note that `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not supported in Access SQL.

Comment: @HansUp thank you for that (I didn't actually know that) So will add that into answer as clarification

Comment: Thanks MrCoder. Great explanation. If anyone is interested, a full outer join can be simulated in Access using the method described in the following article. http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3516561/Implementing-the-Equivalent-of-a-FULL-OUTER-JOIN-in-Microsoft-Access.htm

Answer (score 1):

Using `in` and `not in` translate to very long `and` or `or` statements by the pre parser.

So `ABC IN(1,2,3,4)` translates to `(ABC = 1 OR ABC = 2 OR ABC = 3 OR ABC = 4)`

Similarly for `NOT IN`, although probably using `AND`s in the actual query processing.

This can result in poor performance of queries, if there is a large (*-ish*) number of values in the `IN` or `NOT IN`.

It might be best to redesign your query to use joins instead, as the database engines are highly optimized for fast Joins.

EDIT: Explained the pitfalls of using `IN` or `NOT IN` a bit better